# How to get data list from Query String in vb.net

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, vb.net

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetVehicleModels(ByVal vehicleval As String) As List(Of newvehicle)
    Return FillModels(vehicleval)
End Function
Public Shared Function FillModels(ByVal makeid As String) As List(Of newvehicle)

    Dim cnCos As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCos As String = "Select VehicleModelName + ' ' + VehicleCC + ' CC' AS VMN, VehicleModelID FROM VehicleModels WHERE VehicleMakeId=0 OR VehicleMakeID = " & makeid & " ORDER BY VehicleModelName"
    Dim cmdCos As New SqlCommand(sqlCos, cnCos)
    cmdCos.CommandTimeout = MIS.DBTier.dbTimeOut
    cnCos.Open()

    cnCos.Close()
    cnCos = Nothing
    cmdCos = Nothing

End Function
```

i am beginner in development filed.  Actually on change i want to fill other drop down i have done this further how i can get data from query string to pass back ajax. My Ajax call is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMake").change(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "newvehicle.aspx/GetVehicleModels",
                data: '{vehicleval: "' + $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMake").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlModel').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value["_Id"]).text(value["_vehicleName"]));
                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });

        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Are you simply asking how to get a list of your data from the sql database?